# Netsuite compare 2 datetime in saved search criteria

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I would like to send an email if my URL is expired.
For that, I have created a saved search and a custom transaction field.

My goal is to show the transaction record in the saved search, from the moment the date is expired.
I tried with `formula date` but it return only if the date is before today. But it can happen that we are the same day and that the url is expired for 1min or 1hour.
Ex: Today = 13/09/2022 **3:00** pm and expiration date is 13/09/2022 **2:59** pm
So I tried with Formula numeric to do:

```
{customfield} - {today} is less than 0
```

But Netsuite return an unknown error.
So I tried:

```
TO_CHAR((NVL({customfield},{today})-{today})) is less than zero
```

But it return this kind of value so it's always zero

```
+000000000 20:57:33.000000
```

or

```
-000000000 02:26:33.000000
```

or

```
+000000000 00:00:00.000000
```

How can I do to send an email when the DateTime from my custom field is in the past?

Answer (score 0):

The formula type you select specifies the data type for the result returned.  When you select "Formula (Date)" (`formuladate`) or "Formula (Date/Time)" (`formuladatetime`), NetSuite will convert the returned difference into a time interval formatted as a date or timestamp.  For numerical comparison, use "Formula (Numeric)" (`formulanumeric`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using a formula numeric field and a custom date/time field to compare to the current date/time. I found the solution in a SuiteAnswers article:

Formula column: Enter

```
TO_DATE({‌today}) - TO_DATE({‌custrecord882})
```

***Note:*** This formula displays the whole number of days rounded up. (E.g., the difference of 7.62 is rounded up to 8 days.)

Formula column: Alternatively enter

```
ROUND(to_number(cast({‌today} as date) - cast({‌custrecord882} as date)),2)
```

***Note:*** This formula displays the number of days precisely to two decimal places.

I couldn't get the first one to work, but the second one is working for me after I typed it in instead of copying and pasting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).